# easy way to copy to clipboard from windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt

I often type long command lines in the windows command prompt.  When I get a failure I want to copy that command line to the clipboard so I can use it in my debugger.

Using Edit->Mark is really inconvenient when the command line is more than one line.  At easy way to do copy the command line to clipboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Console2: http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/ you can shift+drag to make selections. Or you can go to preferences in CMD and turn on quick select mode.

Comment: I might get Console2 for its multi-tab feature.  Hmm I might also just recompile it with a copy-cmd-line feature!

Answer (score 8):

`doskey /history | clip` is a start.  You could write a batch file to pull just the last line out of the history if you wanted to be a bit more accurate.